# How do I set up RPM on a manual install CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

I am following the instructions from the CentOS website to manually install CentOS 7 (http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/ManualInstall) but the guide seems to have some quality issues. I've partitioned the storage fine and now onto setting up RPM. Unfortunately I am at a loss on how to do this. I am doing this on VMware Workstation 10 and the host OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Why are you using those directions instead of just installing from installation media? What step in those directions are you having trouble with exactly? Those directions are also quite rough and clearly under-specified in a number of places. I would suggest not using them and using installation media normally.

Comment: I read on a devops website it's a good skill to have. But I am coming to the realisation that no one does this because there are absolutely no guides for this apart from the crappy one on the centos website. My ultimate aim is just to improve my understanding of Linux.

Comment: What website said that what is a good skill to have? Manually boot-strapping a packaged distro by hand?

Comment: http://www.opsschool.org/en/latest/

Comment: Are you talking about "Bare-Metal Provisioning 101 - Install CentOS by hand"? Is there more to that than the heading? Because given just that heading (and the one after it) that seems more to me like "walk through the CentOS installer" than "manually bootstrap the OS".